# In spritekit I cant pop GameCenter view

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, game-center, game-center-leaderboard

I am making a game with sprite kit , and all went fine before I use `GameCenter` inside  , Here is my code

```
define the Gameviewcontroller:

var GameController:GameViewController = GameViewController()
```

When you touch the node inside the `TouchecBegan` :

```
    let touchLocation = (touches as NSSet).anyObject()?.locationInNode(self)

    let targetNode = self.nodeAtPoint(touchLocation!)

    if targetNode.name == "leader"{

        print("hhhh")

        GameController.showGamecenetr()

    }
```

and inside the `GameViewController` the code of `ShowGameCenter`:

```
func showGamecenetr() {

    print("jijijijji")

    GameKitHelper.sharedInstance.showGKGameCenterViewController(self)

}
```

It should pop the view of `GameCenter` , but it shows the error:

could not cast value of type `UIView` to `SubView`

I found that it is a very easy error , but I never met it here before , I don't know how to handle it ,Can anybody help me ?

Here are the code that inside `showGKGameCenterViewController()`

```
func showGKGameCenterViewController(viewController:UIViewController!){

    if !gamecenterEnable {

        print("No user!")
        return 
        }

    let gameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()

    gameCenterViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self

    gameCenterViewController.viewState = .Leaderboards
    viewController.presentViewController(gameCenterViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)

    }
```

help help ;(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i assume you authenticated your local player/user.
To open `GameCenter` just do it like this in your scene

```
override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {

    for touch in touches {
        let location = touch.locationInNode(self)
        let touchedNode = nodeAtPoint(location)

        if targetNode.name == "leader"{
            let gcViewController: GKGameCenterViewController = GKGameCenterViewController()
            gcViewController.gameCenterDelegate = self

            gcViewController.leaderboardIdentifier = kLeaderboardID

            gcViewController.viewState = GKGameCenterViewControllerState.Leaderboards
            let vc: UIViewController = self.view!.window!.rootViewController!
            vc.presentViewController(gcViewController, animated: true, completion: nil)  
        }
    }
}
```

`GKGameCenterControlleDelegate` in your scene

```
class GameScene: SKScene, GKGameCenterControllerDelegate {
```

And

```
func gameCenterViewControllerDidFinish(gameCenterViewController: GKGameCenterViewController) {

    AppDelegate().resumeBackgroundMusic()
    gameCenterViewController.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

Comment: Oh ,dear Darvydas , I am sorry . I just see your message now , I am so happy to see you again really!!! You are so professional !! and so kind !! I wish to make friends with you  really!!!

Comment: Can I have your whatsapp ?

Comment: I tired your code , but The Xcode  cant find GKGameCenterViewController :(